# Using optim() - two equations two unknowns R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to use optim() to solve & maxim. the following equation system:

```
model <- function(z) {
    q1 <- z[1]
    q2 <- z[2]
    return ((10-2*(q1+q2))*q1-k1*q1)
    return ((10-2*(q2+q1))*q2-k2*q2)
}
```

The paramters/variables are defined as follows:

```
A <- rep(0,2)
lowerb <- rep(0,2)
upperb <- rep(6,2) 
k1 <- 3
k2 <- 2
```

and the rest as follows:

```
optim(A, model, gr=NULL, method="L-BFGS-B", lower = lowerb, upper = upperb, control = list(fnscale = -1, trace = 1))$par
```

I do not receive an error, however, the maxima are supposed to be at q1=1 and q2=1,5 and not at 1,75 and 0, as R is stating at the moment. Since I need to apply this to a much more complex equation system, I did use an easy equation to start with, which one can easily calculate manually.

Help is appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: optim(A,model,gr=NULL, method="L-BFGS-B", lower = lowerb,upper = upperb, control = list(fnscale = -1, trace = 1))$par

Comment: How come function `model` "attempts" to return a value twice?

Comment: sorry, I don't even get your question I think. I might be using it wrong, as I said, what I am trying to do is solving the equation for q1 & q2 and those basically are the two profit functions of a cournot duopoly.

Comment: What is the (mathematical) function that you want to optimize?

Comment: pi1 = (10-2(q1+q2))*q2-q2*k2  and pi2 = (10-2(q1+q2))*q1-q1*k1 // I got two, which you usually solve with partial differentiation. The first order conditions are then defining the Nash-Equilibria.

Comment: Well, you are trying to use `optim`, which requires the function to return a scalar (see the documentation), to optimize two functions... That will not work

Comment: hmm.. ok, thanks anyway :). you don't have any idea what to use instead by any chance?

Comment: In this case, you need a function that performs "multi-objective optimization". Take a look at packages `goalprog` and `mco`...

Comment: You might want to have a look at `GNE.nseq(...)` in package `GNE`.

Comment: ok. thanks! I will have a look!

Answer (score 1):

```
k1 <- 3
k2 <- 2
q2 <- 0
q2 <- 0 
for (i in 1:20) {
  #For 1
  objective1 <- function(q) ((10-2*(q+q2))*q-k1*q)
  result1 <- optimize(objective1, c(0,10), maximum = TRUE)
  q1 <- result1$maximum 
  #For 2
  objective2 <- function(q) ((10-2*(q1+q))*q-k2*q)
  result2 <- optimize(objective2, c(0,10), maximum = TRUE)
  q2 <- result2$maximum 
  }
q1
q2
```